# My app crashes when setting the minSDK to Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tensorflow-android

I have created tensorflow android app and application is still working perfect on lollipop version, i build this app on min sdk lollipop and tested it into marshmallow and nougat but when i convert it into jelly bean 4.1 application got crash and i found this error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "the.tensorflow.signlanguage.ClassifierActivity" on path: /data/app/the.losers.tensorflow.signlanguage-1.apk
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
```

Comment: thank you for your support. i found on internet that it only supported on greater than api 21.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassifierActivity.java` belongs to [demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java) app of tensorflow for Android.

Tensorflow demo examples support only **API level 21 or greater**. It will not work with **JellyBean**.

Check below official information:

> The Android SDK and build tools can be downloaded separately or used
>   as part of Android Studio. To build the TensorFlow Lite Android demo,
>   build tools require API >= 23 (**but it will run on devices with API >=
>   21**).

Link [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_android)

Comment: I think that's for the demo and not for the tensorflow . https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_android

Comment: @AmanChhabra OP `ClassifierActivity.java` belongs to demo app of tensorflow for Android. He is trying to build that app only due to which this error is happening. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java